# I dont see any recruit results even I received the status "OK" and "200" after I set up the Google Indexing API

Tags: php, google-analytics, service-accounts, google-search-console, google-indexing-api

I just set up my Google for Jobs including Indexing API(Using PHP), Service Account and Search Console. But I don't see any recruit results in Google for Jobs even I got status message "OK" and "200"

1. Created my new Google account for Jobs

2.
Created a service account with Google API as an owner(With JSON)
Created a new OAuth authorization information at the same time.

3.
Verified my site ownership with Google Search Console.
Added my service account's e-mail address. 
(just like this one:
XXX@XXXiam.googleserviceaccount.com)

4.
Download the PHP library from
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases

Copy this file "Google-api-php-client" folder into the same directory as recruit HTML.

(Example)
Document/recruit.html
Document/google-api-php-client

---

Download the Indexing files from
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services

Copy these two files which have been downloaded from "Indexing files"

src/Google/Service/Indexing
src/Google/Service/Indexing.php

and paste them into the google-api-php-client folder

(Example)
Document/google-api-php-client
Document/google-api-php-client/Indexing.php
Document/google-api-php-client/Indedxing

---

5. Create the PHP file to for Indexing API(Code below)

6.
Upload all of these files into the server and access the PHP directory with a web browser.

And I got "OK" and "200" starting with GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object ...(I don't know how this is called)

7. About a whole 2 days passed after the access to the PHP directory with a browser. But I still don't see any results on Google for Jobs.

```
<?php

require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

// service_account_file.json is the private key that you created for your service account.
$client->setAuthConfig('X.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');

// Get a Guzzle HTTP Client
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$endpoint = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';

// Define contents here. The structure of the content is described in the next step.
$content = "{
  \"url\": \"https://X.html\",
  \"type\": \"URL_UPDATED\"
}";

$response = $httpClient->post($endpoint, [ 'body' => $content ]);
$status_code = $response->getStatusCode();

print_r($response);
echo "\n";
echo "$status_code";
```

I didn't see any error message but

1. I'm not sure I did the correct thing.
   (Accessing the PHP on the server with browser and confirm the status code 200 and OK is fine?)

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

My index in the robots meta tag was "noindex".
That's all. No relations between any of the indexing API's.

Just a single meta setting.

I would be happy if someone would be helped with this.

Check this! It's an example.

Before (Indexing API replies 403)

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

After (Indexing API replied 200)

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
```

Actually, nothing is required to write in this meta tag :p
if you are thinking to post on google indexing.